# pinned footer inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, border-layout

I would like to pin my footer panel to the bottom of my JPanel, i have tried the following.

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
pane.add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
pane.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
JScrollPane SP = new JScrollPane(pane, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Can you make a test case? You're almost there. Also, you might consider using a [layeredpane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Comment: We need to see your GUI code, everything pertaining to the problem :)

Comment: @matt, I just have JTable inside JScrollPane, and I need footer for it table. Nothing special code. And I'm sorry, I can't to show it all. And I try to use layeredPane, but  I can't pin my footer. I want to have vertical scroll for table, and footer as a table part with horizontal scroll.

Comment: 1) *"I can't to show it all."* We don't need to see all your code, just an example of the problem. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: `I want to have vertical scroll for table, and footer as a table part with horizontal scroll.` - yes, well that is not the way a scrollpane works. The entire panel will scroll. There is no way to keep a footer from scrolling vertically while scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
JPanel child = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
child.add(header, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
child.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(child, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
pane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't. I need to do footer with scroll like on the table

Comment: You need to add the pane Objecto to your Container

Answer (score 0):

I need to do footer with scroll like on the table

A JScrollPane doesn't support this type of functionality. So you somehow need to fake it.

Maybe you can use a second JScrollPane as the footer component. Then you share the model of the horizontal JScrollBar. Using RSDinh's code as a starting point you might do something like:

```
//pane.add(footer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
JScrollPane footerScrollPane = new JScrollPane(footer);
JScrollBar horizontal = footerScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
horizontal.setModel(scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());
```